# Change magento theme

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to change theme in magento 2. The problem is that the client dont want the website to go down for 3 days so I have time to fix the new design and add clients images and information.

If I build the site in subdomain how can I move it to root folder and after that connect the database of the old site without losing any data or do something wrong?

I didn't try anything. I am new to magento so I cant figure out what to do

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to setup git on your project.

Here is an explanation of how to setup git in an existing project

[Add Magento Existing project to Github repository](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311586/add-magento-existing-project-to-github-repository)

When you are finished and the project is in a repo.
Clone the repo to your local environment, also take a database dump from the server and setup the project in the local environment.

And finally you can work and test your code independently without affecting production and when you have finished, with the help of git you can easily transfer to the production instance